# Php oop file upload

Tags: php, oop, upload

I work on a oop php file upload script. Is simple. But doesnt work. What is the problem? I learn how to use $_FILE, and how to code oop style.

Thanks.

upload.php are :

```
<?php
class upload{
    public $src = "./upload/";
    public $tmp;
    public $filename;
    public $type;
    public $uploadfile;

    public function startupload(){
        $this -> filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $this -> tmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $this -> uploadfile = $src . basename($this -> name);
    }
    public function uploadfile(){
        if(move_uploaded_file($this -> tmp, $this -> uploadFile)){
            return true;
        }
    }


}

?>
```

index.php are:

```
<?php 
require_once('./lib/upload.php');
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['file'])){
    $fileupload = new upload();
    if($fileupload -> uploadfile()){
        echo 'Fisierul a fost uploadat';
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form align="center" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
Select upload file: <input type="file" name="file" required="yes"  />
<input type="submit" value="Trimite" />
<p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Where i'm wrong with my tinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is not triggered is because you checked variable file  in the post variable and you wont find it there. the corect way to do it is

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $fileupload = new upload();

    if($fileupload -> uploadfile()) {
        echo 'Fisierul a fost uploadat';
    }
}
```

further more your class will not work you should pass the variables to a constructor and rename upload-> startupload() to upload-> upload

Answer (score 1):

For starters you are never calling startupload().

I would suggest moving that function to the constructor (a function in the class named __construct() )

Pass $_FILES to it so you can work with the input param instead of $_FILES directly.

Comment: There are other issues with the code, but if you are trying to learn oop you will get to those in due time... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the upload code to:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $fileupload = new upload();
    $fileupload->startupload();
    if($fileupload -> uploadfile()){
        echo 'Fisierul a fost uploadat';
    }
}
```

And change this line in you class:

```
$this -> uploadfile = $this -> src . basename($this -> filename);
```

Also this line needs updating because the case it wrong for uploadfile:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($this -> tmp, $this -> uploadfile)){
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create your own contruct where will be complete content of `startupload()` function

look at this:

```
public function __contruct($string){
    $this -> filename = $_FILES[$string]["name"];
    $this -> tmp = $_FILES[$string]["tmp_name"];
    $this -> uploadfile = $this -> src . basename($this -> filename);
}
```

then you couldn't use something like:

```
$fileupload->startupload();
```

but you can write only:

```
$fileupload = new upload("file");
```

and little note finally: 
in PHP all classes must be written with capital

Comment: Class names do not have to begin with a capital letter (think `mysqli`), they just have to be referenced in the same case thier declared in. However it is best practice to define class names in [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Comment: Yes, by the PSR standards you even must declared classes in CamelCase ;) thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_image(){
    $type=explode(".",$_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $type=$type[count($type)-1];
    $url="./studentimage/".uniqid(rand()).".".$type;
    if(in_array($type,array('jpeg','jpg','bmp','png'))){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'],$url)){
                return $url;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        return "sorry dose not match my extention";
    }
}
```