# php oop upload file and check extension

Tags: php, oop

Hei, from [Php oop file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432468/php-oop-file-upload), i update the script with some function. Size check function and extension check function. But somewhere i go wrong with extension check function.

```
<?php
class upload{
    public $src = "upload/";
    public $tmp;
    public $filename;
    public $typefl;
    public $uploadfile;
    public $type = array("php", "css", "js", "html", "htm", ".php");

    function __construct(){
        $this -> filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $this -> tmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $this -> uploadfile = $this -> src . basename($this -> filename);
    }
    public function sizeck(){
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 50000000){
            echo "Fisier prea mare";
            return true;
        }
    }
    public function extens(){
        $this -> typefl = pathinfo($this -> tmp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($this -> typefl, $this -> type)){
            echo "Fisier nepermis!!!";
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }


    public function uploadfile(){
        if(move_uploaded_file($this -> tmp, $this -> uploadfile)){
            return true;
        }
    }


}

?>
```

And call upload is :

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $fileupload = new upload();
    if(!$fileupload -> sizeck()){
        if(!$fileupload -> extens()){
            if($fileupload -> uploadfile()){
                echo 'Fisierul a fost uploadat';
            }
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

Where i do wrong and why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement has `!`, which means it's `true` if your `extens()` returns `false`.

But you wan't to move on, if it's `true`. So remove `!`.

```
if(!$fileupload -> extens()){
```

should be

```
if($fileupload -> extens()){
```

And you can't get extension form `tmp_name`. It should be `name`. `tmp_name` doesn't have extension in it's name.

So change

```
$this -> tmp = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

to

```
$this -> tmp = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Comment: True ...thanks, but file is not check and file with php/html and other extension who is in array, are uploaded without any problem. What are wrong in my code?:(

Comment: See my edited answer. You are getting extension from wrong name.